# Use CSB's theorem to show that |X| = |Y|

Tags: elementary-set-theory

We consider the sets

X = {(x, y) ∈ ℝ × ℝ | |x| + |y| ≤ 1}

Y = {(x, y) ∈ ℝ × ℝ | |x| ≤ 1 and |y| ≤ 1}.

We have "CSB" = Cantor-Schroeder-Bernteins theorem which states that if A and B are sets and there are injective functions f : A → B and g : B → A, then there exists a bijective function h : A → B.

Now show |X| = |Y|.

My problem is in the second part of the sets, I cannot visualize functions representing |x| + |y| ≤ 1 or |x| ≤ 1 and |y| ≤ 1. So if you have any ideas what those look like or a different approach, I'd appreciate your help. the rest to the task i can do myself.

Tips on how to post questions are always welcome. After all, questions have to be somewhat decent.
(I'm really bad at tagging)

Comment: $R$ is meant to be the reals, I assume?

Comment: R is meant to be reals

Comment: Well...one injection is clear, right?

Comment: @lulu do you mean for g : Y → X?

Comment: No, the other way around it easier

Comment: Don't guess blindly.  Start by drawing the two regions.

Comment: I wouldn't use CSB. There's a (relatively) simple bijection which in fact is a metric mapping of distortion 0--- think rotations.

Comment: @lulu thank you for giving me that 'hint'. helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: the two regions are

- $|x|+|y|\leq 1$: the square whose vertices are $(1,0),(0,1), (-1,0)$ and $ (0,-1)$
  [image]
- $|x|\leq 1$ and $|y|\leq 1$: the square whose vertices are $(1,1),(-1,1), (-1,-1)$ and $ (1,-1)$

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Let $f: X \rightarrow Y$ be the map $f(x,y) = (x,y)$. Note that indeed $(x,y) \in Y$ since $|x| + |y| \leq 1 \implies |x| \leq 1, |y|\leq 1$. Clearly this map is injective by definition of an ordered pair.

Now we need to construct a map $g: Y \rightarrow X$ which is injective. One such map is given piecewise, e.g. $g(x,y) = (x-1/2,y-1/2)$ if $x,y \geq 0$. Notice that indeed $|x - 1/2| + |y-1/2| \leq 1$ since $|x|,|y| \leq 1$ and $x,y \geq 0$ And similarly you define $g$ for the other cases: $x \geq 0, y\leq 0$ and $x\leq 0$, $y \geq 0$ and $x \leq 0, y \leq 0$.

Comment: I'm really thankful that you took your time to help me. Actually your first comment broke the blockade in my head to solving this task somehow. So I'm really grateful...